# Scala: Read file from IO and line by line match it construct a case class and add the case class to a List

Tags: scala

I have been trying to learn Scala in my free time and learn to write code in a more functional manner; anyways I have hit a problem trying to write (what I thought) would be a simple tool for reading formatted name data out of a file and creating a List of that data containing case classes... this does not work however:

```
object NameDataUtil {

  /**
   * reads a data file containing formatted name data into a list containing case classes.
   *
   * @param fileName name of the file (with extension) to read the data from.
   * @return a list of case classes containing the data from the specified file.
   */
  def readInFile(fileName: String): List[NameDatum] = {

  val names: List[NameDatum] = Source.fromURL(getClass.getResource("/"+fileName)).getLines() foreach { line =>
    line.trim.split("\\s+")
    match {
      case Array(name,freq,cumFreq,rank) => NameDatum(name, freq.toDouble, cumFreq.toDouble, rank.toInt)
    }
  }

  names
  }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please, always add the full error messages to the question (or partial stack traces).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `foreach` with `map` and you'll get an `Iterator[NameDatum]`. Add a `toList` after `getLines()` to get a `List[NameDatum]` instead, though it's probably better to use `toStream` and work with a `Stream[NameDatum]` instead, if you expect the file to be too big to fit all in memory.

Comment: Thanks Daniel that worked perfectly. Sorry about not providing an error message in the original post. Also thank you to Eric for providing a similar answer just a few moments later as well as a suggestion for using regex for matching.

Answer (score 1):

i think the problem is that you're using foreach, which has a return-type of unit; see the signature of foreach from the following:
http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Iterator

```
def foreach (f: (A) ⇒ Unit): Unit
```

what would do the trick is map, you can see the method signature (as in the above link) is

```
def map [B] (f: (A) ⇒ B): Iterator[B]
```

so when you perform your match on each line, you will map the type A, which is the type of line (i.e., String) to the type B, which is your NameDatum.

also, something you might find interesting is that you can use a regex in a match... this would be an alternative to using the split, check out the technique at the following
http://ikaisays.com/2009/04/04/using-pattern-matching-with-regular-expressions-in-scala/

Comment: Thank you! I accepted Daniel's answer because it was the same answer but his was first. However your regex link is interesting and I am looking into it.